# Is it possible to open the same files every time Photoshop CC Opens?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I work with the same number of templates pretty much every day and I'd like to find a way to have those files automatically open as soon as Photoshop opens. I only know that if you close PS, it will try to open recovery version of that file, but I'm looking to open the most up-to-date versions. I was wondering if Windows would open shortcuts to those files if I stuck them in the Startup folder as an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a Scripts Events Manager system in Photoshop, basically it can play a `script` or an `action` every time a specific event fires.

What you need to do is to create an `action` that would open the files you need, navigate to `File > Scripts > Scripts Event Manager`, select a `Start Application` event, your `Action` and add it to the list. This `action` will play every time you start Photoshop.

[image]

Comment: Spacibo Sergey.